# Full calendar dynamic resources

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I fill a calendar with several dynamic resources in resource view?
In the same way I can retrieve events from a database, I'd like to do it with resources.

In my aplication there are buildings with meeting rooms. I have two views: 1) meeting room view and 2) building view. When I select a building I'd like to see a resource view with all the meeting rooms of that building.

For events i use the next code:

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myJavaClass',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: {
            room: $('#room').val(),
            start: start,
            end: end
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: ($(this).attr('start'),
                    end: ($(this).attr('end'),
                    allDay: false,
                    url: 'MyJavaModifyingClass?id=' + $(this).attr('ref')
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
},
```

Is there an existing code for retrieve resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, just fetch them before rendering your fullcalendar (or destroy and rerender if you need to change them). Example here: https://github.com/ChurchDesk/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/resource-fixed-views.html

Comment: Seeing the example, I guess I have to fill resources manually in jQuery code. In my case, if there is a new meeting room then, will I have to change the code?

Comment: Anyway, @RichardHermanson, it doesn't work. resourceFilter doesn't filter resources checked in html code.

Comment: you don't have to do it "manually". My advice would be to go look at a few tutorials for javascript

Comment: But this is my first question, @RichardHermanson. How can I create resources dynamically? Resources in jQuery code are the same as inputs in html body. Then, resourceFilter activate those that are checked. But it doesn't work in my application.

Comment: There's like a million ways to do it. How you'd want to it depends on where you get the information from. If you just get some JSON from somewhere you can just use something like `var myResources = JSON.parse(resourcesString);` and then give it to fullcalendar like: `...fullCalendar({ resources: myResources, ... });`